# Creating new symfony project on localhost

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I'm trying to run project using newest symfony on my localhost.

What i already did:

I added this to my vhosts file in Xampp.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "F:\Programy\XAMP\htdocs\Anka\web"
    ServerName Anka
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    ErrorLog "logs/vark.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/vark.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I added this in my hosts file in Windows\System32...

```
127.0.0.1 Anka
```

This is what i see after typing

```
 anka\
```

In my browser.
[My localhost website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aStsX.png)

And when i click on **web** i see this:
[web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c33Nm.png)

Can somebody help me what else i should do to see normal Symfony index page?

Comment: Can you comment out `DirectoryIndex app_dev.php` and see what the result is? Also try the debug URL: `http://anka/app_dev.php` in your browser.

Comment: Also will you share your `App/AppKernel.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://anka/app_dev.php` or `http://anka/web/app_dev.php`

Also You can Change the directory to this one with the application and run:

`php bin/console server:run`

Then access `http://localhost:8000/` in your browser

Like this:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#running-the-symfony-application

Answer (score 0):

First of all - `ServerName` value is case-sensitive, to Apache is not really recognizing request as this VirtualHost and you're getting listing of root directory.

Use  `http://Anka` url, or change `ServerName Anka` to `ServerName anka` and `127.0.0.1 Anka` into `127.0.0.1 anka`.

Next thing is that you have some errors in your code and PHP cannot find `AnkaBundle\AnkaBundle` class. You're probably missing an autoloader, but that's only my guess. Not enough information to be sure.